# Is there a way to make the open tabs in Eclipse/Aptana show both the directory and file name?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, aptana

In Eclipse / Aptana Studio is there a setting that allows the tab to show both the directory and file name (instead of just the file name) so I can see:

```
blog/views.py
```

instead of just

```
views
```

Answer (score 1):

If you hover the pointer over the file’s tab, Eclipse will display a tooltip showing the full path and filename.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you open two files with the same name, it will display filename and the directory.  It doesn't look like there is a way to do this by default.

The closest thing I found was showing the file extension in python under Preferences/PyDev/Editor/"Editor caption/icon"